# Webshot for cBioportal produces white image

Tags: r, web-scraping

PROBLEM: I'm trying to take a simple picture of https://www.cbioportal.org/ on webshot but it just produces a completely white png. It works for other websites. Is there something preventing webshot from accessing/ loading it in PhantomJS?

```
webshot("https://www.cbioportal.org", delay = 1,'cbioportal.png')
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I wonder if it's something specific about that site?

Comment: I think so but they have some very useful data/ graphs so it would be really useful to be able to access them. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using webshot, you should consider to try [webshot2](https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2). See [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61479575/1953250) to the similar case.

The code:

```
# Webshot and phantomjs have been previously installed.
library(webshot2)

webshot("https://www.cbioportal.org", delay = 1,'cbioportal.png')
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: I have prepared a blog post including various details about webshot2. You can see the details from http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/export-save-r-graphs-with-webshot/

Comment: Thank you! finally had to time to check this and it works much better than the original webshot on this website. Had some compatibility problems with chromote package but I flagged the issue on their github and it was solved quickly. Thank again!

Comment: @SavvasKourtis It's my pleasure to help you.